# Java 1.4.2's replace() takes in chars only, how can I get a char value of \n and \r\n carriage returns?

Tags: java, replace, char

Java 1.4.2's `replace()` takes in chars only. How can I get a char value of \n and \r\n carriage returns?

```
\n = Unix carriage return 
\r\n = Windows carriage return
```

Comment: You do realize that Java 1.4.2 is really ancient now.  I would suggest looking at moving up to a more current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [String.replaceAll();](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

`String ns = s.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");`

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you'll have to use `replaceAll` ([1.4.2 docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)) which takes a regular expression instead - or one of the bazillion StringUtil libraries available, such as the [Apache Commons "lang" library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Answer (score 3):

The `char` value of `\n` is simply `'\n'`.

There's no `char` value for `\r\n`, because that's **two** `char` values. You'll need to use a different method to do your replacing, if you want to replace that with something else.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String g = "hello world\nI am Soumitra\nHow are you doing??\n\r ";
        System.out.print(g);
        String g1 = g.replaceAll("\\n", " ");
        String g2 = g1.replaceAll("\\r", "X");

        System.out.print("---------After Replacement-----\n");
        System.out.print(g2);
    }
}
```

This will replace the newline(\n)  and carriage return (\r).

Comment: `String g1=g.replaceAll("\\n", " ");` You mean `\n`, not `\\n` (and similarly for `\r`).

Comment: you have to escape the `\` as `\\` that part is correct, the rest isn't the best solution.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: yup...i mean \n(newline) not slash-en and similiarly for \r